# How can I "watch" a file for modification / change?

Tags: python, linux

I would like to invoke my `chrome` or `firefox` browser when a file that I specify is modified. How could I "watch" that file to do something when it gets modified?

Programmatically it seems the steps are.. basically set a never ending interval every second or so and cache the initial modification date, then compare the date every second, when it changes invoke X.

Comment: Follow this tutorial on using inotify [Inotify Example: Introduction to Inotify with a C Program Example](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/inotify-c-program-example/)

Comment: This is not a duplicate question, as that question is about windows.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As noted, you can use [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki/Tutorial):

E.g.:

```
import webbrowser
import pyinotify

class ModHandler(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):
    # evt has useful properties, including pathname
    def process_IN_CLOSE_WRITE(self, evt):
            webbrowser.open(URL)

handler = ModHandler()
wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, handler)
wdd = wm.add_watch(FILE, pyinotify.IN_CLOSE_WRITE)
notifier.loop()
```

This is more efficient than polling.  The kernel tells you when it does the operation, without you having to constantly ask.

Comment: Thank you, thank you.  This is great.  Is there a similar lib for Windows (for compatibility reasons)?

Comment: @sdolan, Windows has [Directory Change Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365261%28VS.85%29.aspx).  There are cross-platform solutions like pyqt's [QFileSystemWatcher](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qfilesystemwatcher.html).

Comment: @sdolan - also, PyGTK has the GIO file monitor.

Comment: @sdolan just to clarify, mhammond's win32 extensions for windows include the dir change notifications.  there is a great example here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/156178-watching-a-directory-under-win32/

Comment: link is broken. Please fix it.

Answer (score 9):

The Linux Kernel has a file monitoring API called inotify. A python binding is [pyinotify](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/).

With it, you can build what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Install inotify-tools and write a simple shell script to watch a file.

Answer (score 2):

The other option is to use a checksum.  You can use a pattern similar to nose's nosy.py.  I use the one from [dingus](http://bitbucket.org/garybernhardt/dingus/src/tip/nosy.py) to check my directory for modifications and run the test suite.

Answer (score 2):

Use [FAM](http://people.gnome.org/~veillard/gamin/python.html) to put a monitor on the file.

Answer (score 1):

use a quick hash function, a cron job, and off you go!

Also, this looks relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, [watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog) works on both Linux & OSX that can be used to monitor for changes in a directory as well with great example documentation. It also works with python3.x in case you don't want to be forced to use python2.x