# Script/App that automatically compiles and compresses js files as you save

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, automation, compression

I'm building a web site and have multiple js files all in one directory.  When I save any one of the js files I want a script to run that will compile and compress all files using the google closure compiler jar.

Example from Google Closure Compiler README:

`java -jar compiler.jar --js=in1.js --js=in2.js ... --js_output_file=out.js`

Is there a shell script or app that does this? I'm looking for something similar to how http://incident57.com/less/ works for CSS.

Comment: Somewhat relevant, although you SHOULD specify OS.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274334/how-can-i-watch-a-file-for-modification-change

Comment: Mac OS X.  thanks meder.  This is a good start.  I'm looking for an app/script that watches a specific folder for when any file in that directory is modified.

Comment: Compiling JavaScript? I'm behind the times.

Comment: @Bears: It's just a catchy name for a compressor with some garbage removal. I tend to call it Google Closure Compressor

Comment: It does do a bit more than compress your JS.  It also checks for compile-time errors.  But it is true it's not what you would typically think of as a compiler since it compiles down to JS and not to assembly, byte code, or some other language.

Answer (score 3):

In linux you can use the **inotifywait** command to listen for changes in a specific folder.
This script can you give an idea:

```
#!/bin/bash

directory=$1

inotifywait -q -m --format '%f' -e modify -e move -e create -e delete ${directory} | while read line

do
    echo "doing something with: $line";

    # for example:
    # java -jar compiler.jar --js=in1.js --js=in2.js ... --js_output_file=out.js 
done
```

You can invoke this script specifying the "monitor" directory, in this way

```
./inotify.sh ~/Desktop/
```

Answer (score 0):

Linux and Mac OSX have application interfaces that let you monitor filesystem changes.

I'm myself using linux so I'm familiar with [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify). Doing a script that compresses your files would be easy enough that I could do it for you from a feasible price.

For Mac OSX you can use [FSEvents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FSEvents) to get a same effect. Though you'll need to do it yourself.

If you wonder how to do this on windows.. Well nobody in his full senses would be using that system for software development.

Answer (score 0):

If you use some eclipse-like IDE, you can create and set builder for this.

But your project should also has "Build Automatically" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Fileconveyor is a Python script that watches and processes files, and can even upload them automatically.

I'd recommend checking out the website to see if it's something that might help you: http://fileconveyor.org/