# How do i watch python source code files and restart when i save?

Tags: python, nodemon

When I save a python source code file, I want to re-run the script. Is there a command that works like this (sort of like nodemon for node)?

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions google offered? There's a lot so I don't know what you may or may not have found yet

Comment: well, i saw a program called "watchdog" but it looks like a programmatic library rather than a command line program like "nodemon". I'm just looking for something that works more or less out of the box like nodemon.

Comment: This question may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274334/how-can-i-watch-a-file-for-modification-change

Comment: There are programs that will save the script upon running, which is pretty much the same thing.

Comment: it looks like pynotify might be what i need. but i'm having trouble installing it as a comman rather than a library

Comment: $python3 -m pynotify hello.py

/usr/bin/python3: No module named pynotify.__main__; 'pynotify' is a package and cannot be directly executed

Comment: so the question is, how can i execute pynotify like a command, or is it only a library?

Comment: Got inspired to write a Docker image which integrates unittest, nose and nodemon (thanks, bkinsey808). Needs a little modification to suit your specific need. Find it [here](https://github.com/poppash/pynosemon).

Answer (score 153, accepted):

While there are probably ways to do this within the python ecosystem such as watchdog/watchmedo ( https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog ), and maybe even linux scripting options with inotifywait ( https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait ), for me, the easiest solution by far was... to just use nodemon! What I didn't know is that although the github tagline of nodemon is "Monitor for any changes in your node.js application and automatically restart the server - perfect for development" actually nodemon is a delicously generic tool and knows that .py files should be executed with python for example. Here's where I think the magic happens: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/c1211876113732cbff78eb1ae10483eaaf77e5cf/lib/config/defaults.js

End result is that the command line below totally works. Yay!

```python
$ nodemon hello.py
[nodemon] starting `python hello.py`
```

Comment: I am trying to use PyInquirer, when using `python` it works, but using `nodemon` gives me `assert self.stdin.isatty()` AssertionError. Using `nodemon` 2.0.3

Comment: with `npx`'s ability to run node executables and wanting to clear the screen on each run, I've been using `npx nodemon --exec "clear;python3" hello.py`, which I discovered from https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1318. Figured others might appreciate this approach as well.

Comment: @kd12345, yes, see answers

Comment: @bkinsey808 but how do i install it with pip?

Comment: @kd12345 nodemon is installed with nodejs. Install nodejs first, then `npm i -g nodemon`

Comment: @bkinsey808 i already have nodemon installed, should i just use it in django the same way i use it in node?

Comment: @kd12345 i think so. I'd have to see what you are doing to know better.

Comment: Haa Really helpful and really really simple. who knew that nodemon iteslef will be able to do it.   I am happy thanks to you bro.

Comment: straight from `nodemon --help`: `nodemon --exec python app.py`

Answer (score 95):

You can install nodemon to watch for file changes.

e.g.

```
npm i -g nodemon
```

Then to use:

```
nodemon --exec python3 hello.py
```

This is for when you use python3 in the command line. On windows you can also use 'py' instead.

Comment: I see. That must in the case where you use python3 in the commandline instead of just the python command. Good to know!

Comment: This does sometime cause issues where it fails to kill the subprocess and spawns a new one. Any suggestions?

Comment: in windows you should use python instead of python3 -> in my case -> "nodemon --exec python server.py"

Comment: this is what I ended up using but I wonder how to pass arguments like you would with `npm run python-script -- --verbose`. I want the verbose argument to get passed to python. Using `nodemon -e py -I --exec \"python server.py\"`

Answer (score 25):

The most similar way to nodemon I found is by using the watchdog package:

```
pip install watchdog
```

This comes with a utility called watchmedo:

```
watchmedo shell-command \
 --patterns="*.py" \
 --command='python "${watch_src_path}"' \
 .
```

Now just work on your `.py` and it will be executed every time you save the file.

Comment: Perfect even for GUI applications `watchmedo auto-restart -p "*.py" -R python3 -- application.py`! Use `watchmedo auto-restart -h` to view the help.

Comment: Seems to not work on Windows 10. `module 'os' has no attribute 'setsid'`

Answer (score 8):

I just use `npx nodemon pythonfile.py`
and it works.Make sure you are using nodemon v2.0.x
or above

Comment: simple + 0 config solution right here.
This is the correct answer

Comment: One of the reasons why I love the node ecosystem

Answer (score 5):

I have used **py-mon** to watch for file changes.

**Installation**

```
pip install py-mon
```

**Execution**

```
pymon filename.py
```

below is the link of package :

https://pypi.org/project/py-mon/

Answer (score 3):

You actually can use nodemon with python, from their docs:

> Running non-node scripts nodemon can also be used to execute and
> monitor other programs. nodemon will read the file extension of the
> script being run and monitor that extension instead of .js if there's
> no nodemon.json:
>
> `nodemon --exec "python -v" ./app.py`
>
> Now nodemon will run app.py with python in verbose mode (note that if
> you're not passing args to the exec program, you don't need the
> quotes), and look for new or modified files with the .py extension.

https://github.com/remy/nodemon#running-non-node-scripts

Answer (score 0):

The watchmedo/watchdog command that gets closest to nodemons behaviour might be:

```bash
watchmedo auto-restart \
 --patterns="*.py" \
 --recursive \
 --no-restart-on-command-exit \
 --debounce-interval 0.1 \
 foo/bar.py
```

as `shell-command` didn't initially start the process, but `auto-restart` did.

`--debounce-interval` was required to avoid `OSError: [Errno 26] Text file busy` errors when files are changed.

Make sure the python file (bar.py in this example) has the correct shebang: `#!/usr/bin/env python3`. Using `env` in the shebang makes it work with poetry and the likes.