# How to run python 3 with nodemon?

Tags: python-3.x, nodemon

I have a simple script in python 3. I want to run with nodemon so that it can start automatically when the file changes. On [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) npm, I have this code : `nodemon --exec "python -v" ./app.py`. The issue is that python version 3 is not enforced.

my python file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print "hello world!"
```

This code is working perfectly, this means Python 3 is not enforced.

How can I use nodemon and make sure it use Python 3 instead of 2?

Comment: The "shebang" is only used when you do e.g. `./app.py` to run the script directly, that's how the shell chooses the executable. If you do `python ./app.py`, it uses the executable *you specifically asked for*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use this:

```
nodemon --exec python3 hello.py
```

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49355010/how-do-i-watch-python-source-code-files-and-restart-when-i-save), it works well for me.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27788902)

Comment: @IvanAracki Thanks for rectifying, it's my first time to answer question, i will answer according to your suggestions and community rules for the next time.

Answer (score 1):

I found a better solution: I just install [reload](https://pypi.org/project/reload/) and run `reload ./myscript.py`. Voilà

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the `py-mon` Python package to achieve the same functionality.

#### Installation

```
pip install -U py-mon
```

#### Execution

```
pymon app.py
```

You can see more arguments here: https://pypi.org/project/py-mon/