# Make local server reload code after changes

Tags: python, localserver

I have files `index.html` and `style.css`  I want to test using a local server, which I do by running `python -m http.server`.

If I make a change to file `style.css` (i.e. a file that is not `index.html`), then when I reload the page I'd like to see the corresponding update. When this actually happens, on the terminal the following appears:

```
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [11/Aug/2022 09:55:24] "GET /style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

but this happens very inconsistently: more often than not, when I make a change to the file and reload the page, it doesn't update at all.

What can I do so that each time I reload the page, the server reloads `style.css`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press CTRL + F5 force browser to get data from server immediately not from browser's cache.

Answer (score 2):

In your browser you could open up Inspect Element (CNTRL+SHIFT+I).
Here you go to the settings icon > Preferences > Network. There is a option called `Disable cache (while DevTools is open)`. If you enable this you should not have to manually force reload the site.

Comment: This is what I personally always use. This way you can just refresh using ctrl + R which is easier to reach on my keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but 200 code is for succes code OK so there might be some problem saving the css file

Answer (score 0):

Other than what others said, when programming servers with node.js I used `nodemon` to automatically reload it based on any change, be it code or CSS, but I still needed to reload the page.

Nonetheless, it is super handy and can also be used with python. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65021005/how-to-run-python-3-with-nodemon).