# Python - Restart a Werkzeug Server Programmatically from within the Script (no from Terminal and not Config file)

Tags: python, restart, nodemon, werkzeug, watchdog

### Question

- *Is There a way to **auto-restart** a Python Werkzeug server from the code base, dynamically, same of what you can do with Watchdog or nodemon but?*

Also important it should not be done from **terminal** nor from a **config file**, because these are not reachable.

### Objective

I need to programmatically write new peace of code within the server code base which also requires a database migration, hence the server needs to **re-start**, all of this in run time and while the  server **is running**

### Mode Details

Basically, I've a Werkzeug server, similar to Flask which I require to auto re-start, I've found this but gives a solution in a command line:

- [How do i watch python source code files and restart when i save?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49355010/how-do-i-watch-python-source-code-files-and-restart-when-i-save)

An instance would be

```
def do_some_computation(restart_server=False):
    """Sample code"""
    watchdog_obj = object()
    computation = 'SOME_COMPUTATION'
    for c in computation:
        print("computing...")
        print("writing new python code to file x...")
    if restart_server:
        watchdog_obj.restart_server_now()


do_some_computation(restart_server=True)
```

Then on the server log terminal I would expect

```
2021-21-21 .....  Initiating shutdown
2021-21-21 .....  Hit CTRL-C again or send a second signal to force the shutdown.
2021-21-21 .....  AutoReload watcher
2021-21-21 .....  HTTP service (werkzeug) ...
```

### Is this possible?